# Using Python tuples as vectors

Tags: python, tuples

I need to represent immutable vectors in Python  ("vectors" as in linear algebra, not as in programming).  The tuple seems like an obvious choice.

The trouble is when I need to implement things like addition and scalar multiplication.  If `a` and `b` are vectors, and `c` is a number, the best I can think of is this:

```
tuple(map(lambda x,y: x + y, a, b)) # add vectors 'a' and 'b'
tuple(map(lambda x: x * c, a))      # multiply vector 'a' by scalar 'c'
```

which seems inelegant; there should be a clearer, simpler way to get this done -- not to mention avoiding the call to `tuple`, since `map` returns a list.

Is there a better option?

Comment: "not to mention avoiding the call to tuple, since map returns a list".  You can avoid the cost of creating a temporary list by replacing map with itertools.imap, which returns an iterator.

I believe that in Python 3.x map will always return a iterator.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[NumPy](https://numpy.org/) supports various algebraic operations with its arrays.

Comment: +1 for numpy.  Numpy's arrays probably already do 95% of what you want.  There's no sense trying to re-implement well-known, and long-used libraries.

Answer (score 11):

Immutable types are pretty rare in Python and third-party extensions thereof; the OP rightly claims "there are enough uses for linear algebra that it doesn't seem likely I have to roll my own" -- but all the existing types I know that do linear algebra are **mutable**!  So, as the OP is adamant on immutability, there *is* nothing for it but the roll-your-own route.

Not that there's all that much rolling involved, e.g. if you specifically need 2-d vectors:

```
import math
class ImmutableVector(object):
    __slots__ = ('_d',)
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        object.__setattr__(self, _d, (x, y))
    def __setattr__(self, n, v):
        raise ValueError("Can't alter instance of %s" % type(self))
    @property
    def x(self): 
        return self._d[0]
    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._d[1]
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._d == other._d
    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self._d != other._d
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self._d)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return type(self)(self.x+other.x, self.y+other.y)
    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        return type(self)(self.x*scalar, self.y*scalar)
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%s, %s)' % (type(self).__name__, self.x, self.y)
    def __abs__(self):
        return math.hypot(self.x, self.y)
```

I "threw in for free" a few extras such as `.x` and `.y` R/O properties, nice string representation, usability in sets or as keys in dicts (why else would one want immutability?-), low memory footprint, `abs(v)` to give `v`'s vector-length -- I'm sure you can think of other "wouldn't-it-be-cool-if" methods and operators, depending on your application field, and they'll be just as easy.  If you need other dimensionalities it won't be much harder, though a tad less readable since the `.x`, `.y` notation doesn't apply any more;-) (but I'd use genexps, not `map`).

Comment: +1 for follow-through!  I do want an n-dimensional solution (and it looks like I'll probably go with NumPy and rethink mutability) but this is worth thinking about.

Answer (score 9):

Although using a library like NumPy seems to be the resolution for the OP, I think there is still some value in a simple solution which does not require additional libraries and which you can stay immutable, with iterables.

Using the `itertools` and `operators` modules:

```
imap(add, a, b) # returns iterable to sum of a and b vectors
```

This implementation is simple. It does not use lambda neither any list-tuple conversion as it is iterator based.

```
from itertools import imap
from operator import add
vec1 = (1, 2, 3)
vec2 = (10, 20, 30)
result = imap(add, vec1, vec2)
print(tuple(result))
```

Yields:

```
(11, 22, 33)
```

Comment: I am working with Python3 in a RaspberryPi Zero and I get
`ImportError: cannot import name 'imap'`

Comment: I fixed the answer's code: for python 3 use map instead of imap.

Answer (score 8):

By inheriting from tuple, you can make a nice Vector class pretty easily. Here's enough code to provide addition of vectors, and multiplication of a vector by a scalar. It gives you arbitrary length vectors, and can work with complex numbers, ints, or floats.

```
class Vector(tuple):
    def __add__(self, a):
        # TODO: check lengths are compatable.
        return Vector(x + y for x, y in zip(self, a))
    def __mul__(self, c):
        return Vector(x * c for x in self)
    def __rmul__(self, c):
        return Vector(c * x for x in self)

a = Vector((1, 2, 3))
b = Vector((2, 3, 4))

print a + b
print 3 * a
print a * 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not create your own class, making use of 2 Cartesian point member variables? (sorry if the syntax is a little off, my python is rusty)

```
class point:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        #etc

    def add(self,p):
        return point(self.x + p.x, self.y + p.y)

class vector:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.pointA=a
        self.pointB=b
        #etc

    def add(self,v):
        return vector(self.pointA + v.pointA, self.pointB + v.pointB)
```

Comment: Primarily to avoid wheel-reinvention; there are enough uses for linear algebra that it doesn't seem likely I have to roll my own.

Comment: @Etaoin You're already reinventing the wheel if you're trying to use your own tuples instead of using a vector class created by someone else. :D

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I fixed up that syntax for you (for the benefit of future readers)

Answer (score 2):

For occasional use, a Python 3 solution without repeating lambdas is possible via using the standard operator package:

```
from operator import add, mul

a = (1, 2, 3)
b = (4, 5, 6)

print(tuple(map(add, a , b)))
print(tuple(map(mul, a , b)))
```

which prints:

```
(5, 7, 9)
(4, 10, 18)
```

For serious linear algebra computations using numpy vectors is the canonical solution:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])

print(a+b)
print(a*b)
```

which prints:

```
[5 7 9]
[ 4 10 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since pretty much all of the sequence manipulation functions return lists, that's pretty much what you're going to have to do.